# como contar la letras de una palabra introducida por consola haciendo uso del for en kotlin

Tags: bucle-for, kotlin, bucles

Hola deseo seber cuantas letras tiene una palabra (inclucyendo los espacio) atraves de un ciclo for en Kotlin este el codigo  del cual me manda un error

```
    var palabra ="hola"
for(x :Int  in  palabra.length  ){
println(x)
    }
```

cabe señalar  que estoy empezando a utilizar el ciclo for
gracias por su ayuda nuevamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El ciclo **for** es una utilidad para recorrer miembro a miembro de un elemento compuesto por más elementos o por un rango de valores definido.
El problema que tienes allí es que estás intentando acceder a cada uno de los miembros de un número y Kotlin no tiene miembros en un número por lo que la operación es inválida.

Primero la consulta que se produce al escribir `palabra.length` hace que te retorne un número conteniendo la cantidad de letras en tu variable paalabra, como esto no es un rango entonces no te funciona. Si solo quieres ver la longitud de una palabra específica puedes escribir:

```
println(palabra.length)
```

Si quieres recorrer cada uno de los miembros de la variable `palabra` y hacer operaciones con cada uno de sus miembros (cada letra) tienes varias opciones:

```
for(letra in palabra) {
    println(letra);      
}
```

*Un ciclo **for** que recorre cada miembro e imprime cada miembro (letra)*

```
for(i in 0..palabra.length) {
    println(palabra[i]);      
}
```

*Un ciclo **for** que recorre el rango que hay entre **0** a **palabra.length**  y almacena un valor en la variable i para luego recorrer el elemento i de la palabra e imprimirlo*

Comment: gracias compañero feliz dia